# Correct working thousand separator with locale awareness in Django 4.04

Tags: python, django, locale

I'm looking for any possibility to humanize values not in general but for some selected values. To be more specific, it's about thousand separator. Enabling thousand separator like this:

**settings.py**

```
USE_L18N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

**views.py**

```
def test (request):
    return render (request, 'example.html', {'example_context_int': 1000})
```

**example.html**

```
#...
{% load_humanize %}
{{ example_context_int }}
```

generates `1.000` as output. This is followed by at least two problems:

1. using any integer given by context as reference for creating links (e.g. passing object id) leads to something like `link-to/1.000/` instead of `link-to/1000/`.
2. pre-populating forms with any integer > 999 forces conversion to a float instead of an integer after submit (e.g. pre-populated `1.000` becomes `1` instead of `1000`).

[This is a known issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19229).

**I got two possibilities to solve this:**

1. using `|stringformat:"s"` for any variable which shall not be humanized or
2. converting every integer which is not allowed to be humanized into a string like `str (example_context_int)`.

Both methods have pros and cons and I don't prefer any of these. What I would prefer is to explicitly humanize values instead of this implicit conversion of all integers and floats. Following [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/humanize/) on that, `|intcomma` have to be used on specific variables instead of set `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True`. But this only works correctly with no other formatting filter set. Using something like `{{ example_context_float|floatformat:2|intcomma }}` will generate `1,000,00` as output instead of localized (German) `1.000,00`. I've also tried to follow [this for controlling localization in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/formatting/), but this is not working as well. Is there any given way to explicitly tell Django which number is allowed to get humanized with correct (= locale aware) thousand separator? Neither documentation nor online research gave solution to that.

If there is no built-in way (or the built-in way has a bug), I appreciate any advice how to get locale aware formatting. Maybe how to build a good working custom template tag for that.

I'm using Django 4.04.

Comment: You should use a `{% url ... %}` tag to generate URLs, and *not* format these with `/link-to/{{ var }}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for that, I will use this tag in future for generating URLs. This seems to be a suitable solution for the first problem when I overcome that `NoReverserMatch` error thrown at first tests. But unfortunately that wrong formatting is not solved by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching through the implementation, the solution is `|floatformat:"2g"` for example. The 'g' means grouped and localized output.

Comment: That's nice! Thx!